# loading xml data to html by ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

Hi i am trying to to develop a voting application using javascript and html. I try to load the senators from a list of xml first time. Ajax call has to be made in order to load the name of voters in html page. If application is run not for first time then from local storage senators are picked up. The problem is i have written the code to drag and drop the senators to respective boxes by loading from xml file.But the voters from xml are not getting displayed once html page gets loaded. 
I am attaching a jsfiddle link plus my xml for you to see it.

```
 xml file: partList.xml
 <senators>
<senator>
    <name>Barbara Boxer</name>
    <party>Democrat</party>
</senator>
<senator>
    <name>Diane Feinstein</name>
    <party>Democrat</party>
</senator>
<senator>
    <name>Al Franken</name>
    <party>Democrat</party>
</senator>
<senator>
    <name>Charles Schumer</name>
    <party>Democrat</party>
</senator>
<senator>
    <name>John Kerry</name>
    <party>Democrat</party>
</senator>

<senator>
    <name>Lamar Alexander</name>
    <party>Republican</party>
</senator>
<senator>
    <name>Kelly Ayotte</name>
    <party>Republican</party>
</senator>
<senator>
    <name>Scott Brown</name>
    <party>Republican</party>
</senator>
<senator>
    <name>Susan Collins</name>
    <party>Republican</party>
</senator>
<senator>
    <name>Orrin Hatch</name>
    <party>Republican</party>
</senator>
```

Javascript code to load xml file to html using ajax call and storing in local storage so that next time local storage is used:

```
        function loadCandidates(fname) {
var xmlhttp;
var txt, xx, x, i, cname, cparty;
var jsonData = [];
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        txt = "";
        x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName(KEY);
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

            txt = txt + "<li draggable='true' id=" + 'c' + i + '' + ">";
            xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("name");
            {
                try {
                    txt += xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</li>";

                    cname = xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                }
                catch (er) {
                    txt = txt + "<li>ffff</li>";
                }
            }
            xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName("party");
            {
                try {

                    cparty = xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                }
                catch (er) {
                    txt = txt + "<li>ffff</li>";
                }
            }
            //Creates a json object to store
            jsonData.push({"name": cname, "party": cparty, "vote": "false"});

        }

        storeToLocal(jsonData);
        document.getElementById('members').innerHTML = txt;
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Loaded "+ x.length+" candidates from AJAX";
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", fname, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

https://jsfiddle.net/q01e2bam/

Comment: i just debugged on chrome it gives this error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. how to solve it if you think i can be done.